# Excel VBA 80040e4d Automation Error connecting to Firebird

Tags: vba, firebird, runtime-error

there.

I'm trying to connect to a Firebird database through Excel 2010 VBA with no success. I'm kind of newbie with this ADO ODBC thing, so I can't figure out the mistake.

I have a **.fdb** file. On my Excel I reference to **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.0 Library**. Then I gone to Firebird site and downloaded and installed the [Firebird ODBC Driver](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/odbc-driver/).

My VBA Code is simple:

```
Dim conn As ADODB.connection

Set conn = New ADODB.connection
conn.Open "DRIVER=Firebird/InterBase(r) driver; UID=SYSDBA; PWD=admini; DBNAME=C:\test.fdb;"
```

My connection string, as stated is **"DRIVER=Firebird/InterBase(r) driver; UID=SYSDBA; PWD=admini; DBNAME=C:\test.fdb;"**

When I run the sub, I get a

> Run-time error '-2147217843 (80040e4d)':
>
> Automation error

What am I missing? What could I do? Do I need a Firebird server installed at my machine and on any clients machine?

Cheers.

Comment: Seems to be a [username/password error](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-339784.html). Double-check your credentials are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't hurt to highlight something: even though you have the FDB file AND the Firebird ODBC Driver, you have to also have Firebird Server installed and running to be able to access the data.

The error message and your described approach description both suggest that you don't have Firebird Server installed and running. Let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: You're right! I really didn't knew this for sure. I'm not used to developing desktop end-user software. The front end is always on web. Thanks, friend!